# How to embed xsl into xml to view in web browser

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been given the following code and need to make some changes to it, but first I'd like to be able to view the result in the browser. 
I'm new at this and don't yet understand the structure of embedding the xsl.

I did try the solutions from a couple of the other "how to embed xsl"-questions, but to no avail.

Can someone show me what needs to be changed in order for this to be valid so it can be seen in the browser:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="statementTitle"/>
    <xsl:param name="customLogoURL"/>
    <xsl:param name="companyLogoURLParam"/>
    <xsl:param name="companyName"/>
    <xsl:param name="DEPARTMENT"/>
    <xsl:param name="moneyFormat"/>
    <xsl:param name="amountFormat"/>
    <xsl:param name="percentFormat"/>
    <xsl:param name="userLocaleSpecificMoneyFormat"/>
    <xsl:param name="userLocaleSpecificAmountFormat"/>
    <xsl:param name="userLocaleSpecificPercentFormat"/>
    <xsl:param name="userLocaleSpecificBonusPercentFormat"/>
    <xsl:param name="userLocaleSpecificDecimalFormatter"/>
    <xsl:param name="EMPID"/>
    <xsl:param name="FIRSTNAME"/>
    <xsl:param name="LASTNAME"/>
    <xsl:param name="DIVISION"/>
    <xsl:param name="LOCATION"/>
    <xsl:param name="TITLE"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="defaultDecimalFormatter" grouping-separator="," decimal-separator="."/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="decimalFormatterDotComma" grouping-separator="." decimal-separator=","/>
    <xsl:decimal-format name="decimalFormatterSpaceComma" grouping-separator=" " decimal-separator=","/>
    <xsl:variable name="companyLogoURL" select="$companyLogoURLParam"/>
    <xsl:template match="/sf-compensation">
        <!--Variable Defnitions go here-->
        <xsl:variable name="empFirstName" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-plan-entry-firstname"/>
        <xsl:variable name="empLastName" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-plan-entry-lastname"/>
        <xsl:variable name="userId" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-plan-entry-userid"/>
        <xsl:variable name="salaryEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-salary/comp-salary-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="promoEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-salary/comp-salary-ineligible/@promo-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="meritEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-salary/comp-salary-ineligible/@merit-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="extraEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-salary/comp-salary-ineligible/@extra-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="extra2Eligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-salary/comp-salary-ineligible/@extra2-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lumpsumEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-salary/comp-salary-ineligible/@lumpsum-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lumpsum2Eligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-salary/comp-salary-ineligible/@lumpsum2-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="bonusEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-bonus/comp-bonus-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stockEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-stock/comp-stock-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stockUnitsEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-stock/comp-stock-ineligible/@units-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stockOptionEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-stock/comp-stock-ineligible/@option-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stockStockEligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-stock/comp-stock-ineligible/@stock-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stockOther1Eligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-stock/comp-stock-ineligible/@other1-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stockOther2Eligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-stock/comp-stock-ineligible/@other2-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stockOther3Eligible" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-stock/comp-stock-ineligible/@other3-ineligible"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cust_current_annual_actual_salary" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-custom-data/comp-custom-field[@id='cust_current_annual_actual_salary']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="merit" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-salary/comp-salary-merit"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cust_total_pct_increase" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-custom-data/comp-custom-field[@id='cust_total_pct_increase']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="cust_final_annual_actual_salary" select="./comp-plan-entry/comp-custom-data/comp-custom-field[@id='cust_final_annual_actual_salary']"/>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>Letter</title>
                <link href="/css/profed/styles.css" media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <link href="/css/profed/print.css" media="print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <style>.hide-textSection{display:none;}.chart-table td.right{white-space: nowrap;} </style>
            </head>
            <body class="statement">
                <!-- begin of text content -->
                <div id="statementContainer">
                    <table id="content" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img alt="Success Factors" src="{$companyLogoURL}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td/>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <div class="spacerPadding2"/>
                                <div class="spacerPadding2"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="borderBottom1" colspan="3">
                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                                    <![CDATA[Private and Confidential<div>[First Name] [[Last Name]</div><div>[Email Address]</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div>]]>
                                </xsl:text>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <div class="spacerPadding2"/>
                                <div class="spacerPadding2"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="400" valign="top">
                                <div id="statement">
                                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                                        <![CDATA[Dear ]]>
                                    </xsl:text>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$empFirstName"/>
                                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                                        <![CDATA[,

        <p>I am writing to confirm that, with effect from 1 June 2020, your gross annual salary will increase to the amount shown.&nbsp; All other terms and conditions of employment remain unchanged.</p><p>I would like to take this opportunity to thank you for your hard work and commitment to SomeCompany and I look forward to working with you over the coming year.</p><p><br></p><p>Yours sincerely</p><p>SomeCompany</p>]]>
                                    </xsl:text>
                                </div>
                                <div id="textSection"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="50"/>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <xsl:if test="$salaryEligible = 'false'">
                                    <table class="chart-table" width="200" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;padding: .5em;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;">
                                                <![CDATA[Salary Review 2020]]>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <![CDATA[Current Gross Annual Salary]]>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="right" valign="top">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($cust_current_annual_actual_salary, $userLocaleSpecificMoneyFormat, $userLocaleSpecificDecimalFormatter)"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <xsl:if test="$merit > 0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <![CDATA[Salary Review Amount]]>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="right" valign="top">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($merit, $userLocaleSpecificMoneyFormat, $userLocaleSpecificDecimalFormatter)"/>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <![CDATA[Salary Review %]]>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="right" valign="top">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($cust_total_pct_increase, $userLocaleSpecificPercentFormat, $userLocaleSpecificDecimalFormatter)"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <![CDATA[Final Gross Annual Salary]]>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="right" valign="top">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="format-number($cust_final_annual_actual_salary, $userLocaleSpecificMoneyFormat, $userLocaleSpecificDecimalFormatter)"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <div id="signature">
                                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                                        <![CDATA[<div>[Signature Image]</div><div><br></div><div><br></div>John Doe<div>Manager</div><div><br></div><div>johndoe@somecompany.it</div><div>Tel. 123456789</div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>[Footer in Blue]</div><div>Some Company</div><div>Registered address: some address</div></div>]]>
                                    </xsl:text>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- end of text content -->
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that it uses disable-output-escaping because that's an optional (and deprecated) feature of XSLT that doesn't work in all browsers. But apart from that, you should be able to get it to run just by adding an xml-stylesheet processing instruction at the start of the XML. What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @MichaelKay So assuming my file is called test.xsl I would add something like <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?> at the top? However, that does not work as intended. That is, the page is rendered as text with tags and all.

Comment: There can be all sorts of reasons for this. The most common ones are (a) the XML document is being sent with the wrong media type, (b) the XML document comes from filestore rather than from an HTTP request and the browser security settings prevent the stylesheet being accessed. The developer console in your browser will probably give some diagnostics.